# How to handle keyboard events JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling

My task is to increase and decrease the size of a "balloon" when pressing the Up and Down arrow keys, respectively. I have set it up as a

tag in HTML and when pressing those keys it has to set the fontsize to something bigger or smaller by 10%. Yet it doesn't work. The size remains the same.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-size: 24px;"></p>
    <button id="temp">Temp</button>
    <script src="tasks.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const balloon = document.querySelector('p');
const defaultSize = balloon.style.fontSize;
balloon.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    let size = balloon.style.fontSize;
    if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
        /*size += 0.1 * size;
        balloon.style.fontSize = size + 'px';*/
        setSize(size * 1.1);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
        while (size > defaultSize) {
            /*size -= 0.1 * size;
            balloon.style.fontSize = size + 'px';*/
            setSize(size * 0.9);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function setSize(newSize) {
    size = newSize;
    balloon.style.fontSize = size + "px";
}

document.getElementById('temp').addEventListener('click', () => {
    setSize(40);
});
```

I set a constant to the p element that holds the balloon symbol and the starting size, to be used when decreasing its size so it couldn't go past a certain size. Next is just listening for the event and if the key is ArrowUp (I tried using the number of the Arrow Up and it didn't work either) then increase the size or if it's ArrowDown, decrease the size. I also override the default behaviour since I'm not sure what it is. The setSize function is temporary, just like the button, to see if either I didn't write the size increase procedure correctly or something else is at fault.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, plain old  JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (click inside the snippet first so it has focus):

```js
const balloon = document.querySelector('p');
const defaultSize = parseFloat(balloon.style.fontSize);
let size = defaultSize;
    
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
        /*size += 0.1 * size;
        balloon.style.fontSize = size + 'px';*/
        setSize(size * 1.1);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
        if (size > defaultSize) {
            /*size -= 0.1 * size;
            balloon.style.fontSize = size + 'px';*/
            setSize(size * 0.9);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function setSize(newSize) {
    size = newSize;
    balloon.style.fontSize = size + "px";
}

document.getElementById('temp').addEventListener('click', () => {
    setSize(40);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-size: 24px;"></p>
    <button id="temp">Temp</button>
    <script src="tasks.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes:

- `size` is defined outside of the event handler, so that the current size is known
- `defaultSize` and `size` are numbers (instead of e.g. `'24px'`)
- The event handler is attached to `window` so that the `keydown` events register
- For `'ArrowDown'`, checking the size using an `if` condition, rather than a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decided to follow your answer. I noticed the eventListener was attached to the wrong element right after writing the question. I didn't actually spot the'pxpx' issue until your answer, so thanks. As for the while .... good spotting, my balloon kept going to bellow the starting size after just one ArrowDown.

Answer (score 0):

You have Two Problem in your code :

First: The Size you Get will get  "24px" not "24" so you Can't Do *1.1 and even set it to `balloon.style.fontSize`

because it will look like

`balloon.style.fontSize="24pxpx"`

Second: Your EventListener set into a wrong position you should set it on Window To listen your click like `window.addEventListener`

And Here is my Simple Demo for you
https://codepen.io/chawol/pen/jOMZbgv

Please forgive me for my bad English

Comment: Thanks, I decided to follow @sbgib's answer. But yours works too (except for ArrowDown).